# Samsung Email: IMAP folders not syncing correctly

Tags: samsung, sync, email, imap, samsung-email

The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S9 Plus and the mail app is [Samsung Email](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.email.provider) version 6.1.75.0. I have created folders on my Android mail app and moved email into them. These folders are not syncing correctly with my mail client I run on the PC (outlook) and are also not visible in the web-based mail portal.

If I create a folder on the phone mail app called 'A1' for instance, it does not sync or appear on any of my other IMAP mail platforms. If I then create a folder using the mail client or web portal called 'A1', it changes the name to 'A1 1' and syncs to the phone correctly. It's as if IMAP knows about the synced folder 'A1' as it won't let me duplicate it, but it is also invisible on the other platforms.

Any ideas?